# How To Test for Duplicate Detection with Azure Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus

I have enabled duplicate detection with my Azure Service Bus. I have set the Duplicate Detection window to 20secs, see image.

[image]

However, when I test with a duplicate message I keep on seeing the message appearing.

Can somene let me know what exactly should happen if I duplicate message is sent?

Updating question to show message_id and Message

[image]

I am sending the following message of 20seconds

[image]

But it keeps on appearing

Comment: Can you share details about how you're publishing messages?

Comment: When you receive the messages, do they have the same `MessageId`?   The `Update MessageId` checkbox is set, and I believe this will populate the field with a unique value on each send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be advised that.

> Enabling duplicate detection helps keep track of the application-controlled *MessageId* of all messages sent into a queue or topic during a specified time window. If any new message is sent with *MessageId* that was logged during the time window, the message is reported as accepted (the send operation succeeds), but the newly sent message is instantly ignored and dropped. No other parts of the message other than the *MessageId* are considered.

> - When **partitioning** is **enabled**, `MessageId+PartitionKey` is used to determine uniqueness. When sessions are enabled, partition key and session ID must be the same.
> - When **partitioning** is **disabled** (default), only `MessageId` is used to determine uniqueness.

and

> Apart from just enabling duplicate detection, you can also configure the size of the duplicate detection history time window during which message-ids are retained. This value defaults to 10 minutes for queues and topics, with a minimum value of 20 seconds to maximum value of 7 days.

See [Duplicate detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/duplicate-detection).

In short: make sure the `Message ID` properties for the two messages are equal. In the Service Bus Explorer in the portal, click the  **Expand Advanced Properties** link and use the `Message ID` field there.
If you're using partitioning, fill in the same Partition Key value under the advanced properties, too.

**EDIT:**
Duplicates are detected within the configured time window. Messages with the same Message ID that have not been sent within the Duplicate Detection time window are not considered duplicates and will be delivered normally.

> Enabling duplicate detection and the size of the window directly impact the queue (and topic) throughput, since all recorded message-ids must be matched against the newly submitted message identifier.

This last quote is probably (partially) the reason 7 days is the maximum time window for duplicate detection.

If you absolutely need duplicate detection for a longer period of time, you could think about implementing a Message ID store yourself and check against that when processing messages.
Since chances of an application sending the same message with the same Message ID after more than 7 days are small, I would probably not invest the extra effort.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for your help on this. One last question. If I have set the Duplicate Detection for 7 days, what happens after the 7th day?

Comment: And what if I don't want duplicates to appear at all? Even after the 7th day?

Comment: @Patterson see updated answer